# importing data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to import a mysql database into a new version of xampp(v7.1.8). Upon pressing the import button I am receiving hundreds of this error messages:

> Notice in .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\UtfString.php#128
>    Uninitialized string offset: 516
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Lexer.php#823: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\UtfString->offsetGet(integer 216)
>   .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Lexer.php#228: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Lexer->parseString()
>   .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Lexer.php#182: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Lexer->lex()
>   .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Parser.php#336: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Lexer->__construct(
>   ,
>   boolean false,
>   )
>   .\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php#395: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser->__construct(string )
>   .\libraries\parse_analyze.lib.php#30: PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Utils\Query::getAll(string )
>   .\import.php#656: PMA_parseAnalyze(
>   string ,
>   string 'where_to_go',
>   )

If anybody can give me any advise, it would be greatly received.

Comment: Which XAMPP version?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be a wrong encoding. If I attempt to import a CSV file saved in Excel, with the format "CSV (character separated) (*.csv) it will be in ANSI. If this file is imported I get the error messages as you. Switch to Windows-1250 in PhpMyAdmin and the file can be read.
If you have a later version of Excel there is the option "CSV UTF-8" (comma seperated)(*.csv). The issue here is, that Excel with European language setting (Dutch, German) the list will not be comma seperated but semi-colon seperated. But you milleage might vary.

Either way. The defaults in both programs are not compatible one has to manually set one or the other.